# Any difference between these 2 imports?

Tags: python

Do the below 2 import statements have some difference? Or just the same thing?

```
from package import *

import package
```

Comment: They are very different, see [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`from package import *` imports everything from package into the local namespace; this is not recommended because it may introduce unwanted things (like a function that overwrites a local one). This is a quick and handy import tool, but if things get serious, you should use the `from package import X,Y,Z`, or `import package` syntax.

`import package` imports everything from package into the local `package` object. So if package implements the `something()` function, you will use it by `package.something()`.

Also, another thing that should be talked about is the nested namespace case: suppose you have the function `package.blabla.woohoo.func()`, you can `import package.blabla.woohoo` and use `package.blabla.woohoo.func()`, but that is too complicated. Instead, the easy way to do it is `from package.blabla import woohoo` and then use `woohoo.func()` or `from package.blabla.woohoo import func`, and then use `func()`. I hope this makes sense. If it doesn't, here's a code piece to illustrate:

```
import package.blabla.woohoo
package.blabla.woohoo.func()

from package.blabla import woohoo
woohoo.func()

from package.blabla.woohoo import func
func()
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the use of a namespace for the package.

```
from package import *
class_in_package()
```

vs

```
import package
package.class_in_package()
```